# Not able to copy file in .Net application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to add authentication for .Net core web app, but when I try to run the code it is unable to copy some files even though I have full access to the system.

I following this doc for web app authentication [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)

Error that I am receiving is

```
Error   MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\userName\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.protecteddata\4.5.0\
runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" to 
"bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll". 
Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4364
```

Comment: You can try to put the dll to a shorter path or use ~/*** if you can, this problem sometimes related to long path.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with exact same `dll` file. Unlike Tisa suggested to put the `dll` to a shorter path, my project was getting the `dll` file from .nuget folder from my user folder like: `C:\Users\nameofuser\.nuget\...path...` which I knew, I shouldn't modify plus I had no idea after modification where should I reference it.

So, for publishing, I moved my project to a shorter path location such as from `C:\Users\nameofuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\repo\Github\projectfolder` to `C:\Users\nameofuser\Desktop\projectfolder` and it worked fine. *Make sure to grant relevant file permissions to Visual Studio after copying/moving the project to a different location.*

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the folder of project to shorter path , it solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).